# RODBC: Why are the values "NA" for empty and space-only values in sqlQuery()?

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am a newbie when it comes to R. I was looking at RODBC results returned from the following:

```
> library(RODBC)
> dbcon <- odbcDriverConnect("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=MYSERV;DATABASE=SOME", tabQuote='', colQuote='')
> sqlQuery(dbcon, "SELECT 3, 'a', ' ', '', NULL")
    .1 .2 .3 .4
1 3  a NA NA NA
```

Why is `' '` and `''` returning `NA`? I can't find anything in the documentation for this behavior. What am I missing?

Comment: You could try it with the `as.is` option

Comment: @Hack-R: That will work but I can't figure out why it tries to convert to NA in the first place without me telling it through something like na.strings. Is there some global parameter that is telling it? How does it know?

Comment: I'm not sure. There is a `nullstring` parameter, but I suppose a blank space isn't technically null. I suppose it's just the default behavior because the package authors thought that more times than not this would be the desired interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So decided to look at the source code for RODBC's `sqlQuery` method since I remembered it was open-source:

```
sqlQuery <-
    function(channel, query, errors = TRUE, ..., rows_at_time)
{
    if(!odbcValidChannel(channel))
       stop("first argument is not an open RODBC channel")
    if(missing(query))
        stop("missing argument 'query'")
    ## could argue that 'max' should restrict rows_at_time
    rows_at_time <- if(missing(rows_at_time)) attr(channel, "rows_at_time")
    else max(1, min(1024, rows_at_time))
    stat <- odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time)
    if(stat == -1L) {
        if(errors) return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel))
        else return(invisible(stat))
    } else return(sqlGetResults(channel, errors = errors, ...))
}
```

so it calls `sqlGetResults`:

```
sqlGetResults <-
    function (channel, as.is = FALSE,
              errors = FALSE, max = 0, buffsize = 1000,
              nullstring = NA_character_, na.strings = "NA",
              believeNRows = TRUE, dec = getOption("dec"),
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
{
    if(!odbcValidChannel(channel))
       stop("first argument is not an open RODBC channel")
    as.df <- function(value, colnames) {
        for(i in seq_along(value))
            if(is.list(value[[i]])) class(value[[i]]) <- "ODBC_binary"
        ## convert list to data frame
        class(value) <- "data.frame"
        names(value) <- make.unique(colnames)
        row.names(value) <- seq(along=value[[1L]])
        value
    }
    cols <- .Call(C_RODBCNumCols, attr(channel, "handle_ptr"))
    ## FIXME: should this be <= 0L?
    if(cols < 0L) {
        if(errors) return("No data")
        else return(invisible(-1L))
    }
    cData <- .Call(C_RODBCColData, attr(channel, "handle_ptr"))
    dbdata <- odbcFetchRows(channel,
                            max = max,
                            buffsize = buffsize,
                            nullstring = nullstring,
                            believeNRows = believeNRows)
    if(dbdata$stat < 0L) {
    if(errors) return(odbcGetErrMsg(channel))
    else return(invisible(dbdata$stat))
    }
    data <- as.df(dbdata$data, cData$names)
    if(nrow(data) > 0L) {
        cols <- ncol(data)
        enc <- attr(channel, "encoding")
        if(length(na.strings))
            for (i in 1L:cols)
                if(is.character(data[,i]))
                    data[data[,i] %in% na.strings, i] <- NA
        if(is.logical(as.is)) {
            as.is <- rep(as.is, length = cols)
        } else if(is.numeric(as.is)) {
            if(any(as.is < 1 | as.is > cols))
                stop("invalid numeric 'as.is' expression")
            i <- rep(FALSE, cols)
            i[as.is] <- TRUE
            as.is <- i
        } else if(length(as.is) != cols)
            stop("'as.is' has the wrong length ", length(as.is),
                 " != cols = ", cols)
        for (i in seq_len(cols)) {
            if(is.character(data[[i]]) && nchar(enc))
                data[[i]] <- iconv(data[[i]], from = enc)
            if(as.is[i] || is.list(data[[i]])) next
            if(is.numeric(data[[i]])) next
            if(cData$type[i] == "date")
                data[[i]] <- as.Date(data[[i]])
            else if(cData$type[i] == "timestamp")
                data[[i]] <- as.POSIXct(data[[i]])
            else
                data[[i]] <- type.convert(as.character(data[[i]]),
                                          na.strings = na.strings,
                                          as.is = !stringsAsFactors,
                                          dec = dec)
        }
    }
    data
}
```

so for string/varchar values it all comes down to:

```
data[[i]] <- type.convert(as.character(data[[i]]),
                                         na.strings = na.strings,
                                          as.is = !stringsAsFactors,
                                          dec = dec)
```

so let's try `type.convert`:

```
> type.convert("a")
[1] a
```

ok, that is expected. Let's try the odd cases now:

```
> type.convert("")
[1] NA
```

hmmm... OK, so that is how we get `NA`

```
> type.convert("       ")
[1] NA
```

ok, that's `NA` too. 
Now, why does `as.is` not return `NA`?

```
if(as.is[i] || is.list(data[[i]])) next
```

aha, it just exits when `as.is` is set and doesn't call `type.convert()`
that explains why it doesn't return `NA` when the `as.is` flag is set